# :visited changing color imidiatly for link for some dont

Tags: html, css

I have some links(ICONS) that i want to be color: orange,:hover color red and :visited color purple. Color is orange and :hover is red, it works. But when i type :visited its not working and it change color of my ICONS to purple as default, and remove :hover:red.

HTML part:

```html
<p>
    <a href="#" class="fab fa-facebook-square"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fab fa-instagram"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fab fa-twitter"></a>
</p>
```

CSS part:

```css
a{
   color: orange;
}

a:hover {
    color: red;
}

a:visited{
   color: purple;
}
```

I expected icons to be orange and when i Visit to be purple.

Comment: I think you have already visited the links before. Do you have the same problem when you open the site in an incognito tab?

Answer (score 0):

If it is visited, then it is visited, so it will be purple. You can't control which links the user has visited before.

`:visited` is stopping `:hover` from applying because CSS rules (when the selectors are equally specific) are applied **in order** and you put `:visited` *after* `:hover`.

Comment: The problems is even i remove all css my ICONS are showing in purple color and not in blue as default

Comment: My other links go back to orange color only Icons stay purple

<li><a href="bussiness_academy_home.html">Home</a></li>
This one go back to orange color